# Tomcat should abort stuck upload threads

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I checked the documentation of Tomcat but didn't find any configuration option for this: Let's simplify the number of status a tomcat HTTP-Thread can have: Ready, Connecting, Service, Finishing

In a scenario without traffic, all http-threads will have status=ready.
If a client request comes in, the status switches to Connecting, then to Service. If all bytes could be delivered to the client, there is a short Finishing status at the end. After that, the thread switches back to Ready, ready for new requests.

If an upload (in status Service) stucks, by that I mean no single byte is sent over 10 seconds, can I tell Tomcat to just abort those threads?

I didn't find an option doing exactly that.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

There are two configuration options:

- connectionTimeout :

> The number of milliseconds this Connector will wait, after accepting a connection, for the request URI line to be presented. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout. The default value is 60000 (i.e. 60 seconds) but note that the standard server.xml that ships with Tomcat sets this to 20000 (i.e. 20 seconds). Unless disableUploadTimeout is set to false, this timeout will also be used when reading the request body (if any).

- connectionUploadTimeout

> Specifies the timeout, in milliseconds, to use while a data upload is in progress. This only takes effect if disableUploadTimeout is set to false.

- keepAliveTimeout

> The number of milliseconds this Connector will wait for another HTTP request before closing the connection. The default value is to use the value that has been set for the connectionTimeout attribute. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout.

Source: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

If you want to protect against blocking while writing to a client, then you should use async servlets and encapsulate the write operations within Hystrix commands.

Comment: Yes, I know these two. But none of these are what I'm looking for. I am looking for an option that aborts STUCK connections only, where really no bytes are being transferred but where the connection is kept alive (for some unknown reason).

Comment: Thanks for `keepAliveTimeout`, does the parameter also apply to responses that have not yet finished but which are stuck?

Comment: What do you understand by "stuck" ?

Comment: stuck = socket is open but no bytes are transmitted